# Cannot assign to read only property with .map(). Recoil with NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, recoiljs

before I use only nextJs everything is good to go but after I try to use recoil and  I try to assign new value to array object by using .map() but the error show up

```
Cannot assign to read only property
```

Here is my example Array object

```
  const [allData, setAllData] = useRecoilState(
    allDataStatte
  );
```

Here is example state AllData

const allData = [
{
id:1,
value:"test1"
},
{
id:2,
value:"test2"
}
]

Here is my code

```
const edit = (listId, value) => {
  allData.map((data) => {
    if (data.id === listId) {
      data.value = value;
    }
  });
};
```

example I want to call edit funcion like this

```
edit(1,"newTitle1")
```

I want my new allData output look like this

```
const data = [
  {
    id:1,
    value:"newTitle1"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    value:"test2"
  }
]
```

I have read someone told that I have to use .slice() to create new object but still not use how to use slice with an array object

Comment: I don't use Recoil, but you shouldn't be trying to directly modify state objects like that (which apparently it actively prevents, which is handy.) Also, [`map` is not for just looping](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/). You probably do want `map` here, but unlike above, you want to actually **use** its return value. ("Probably" because I don't use Recoil.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need to do,

```
const [allData, setAllData] = useRecoilState(allDataState);

const edit = (listId : number, value : string) => {
  let newAllData = allData.map((data) => {
    let newData = {...data};
    if (data.id === listId) {
      newData.value = value;
    }
    return newData;
  });
  setAllData (newAllData);
};
edit(1, 'new value 1');
```

Noticed, newAllData is a new array. Also newData is a new object constructed from data.

Answer (score -1):

it's because of atom  in recoil you have to re create object array and then setState again by using _clondeep or slice